# How can I set the MessageGroupId when using MassTransit SQS?

Tags: amazon-sqs, masstransit

I try to use MassTransit SQS to publish a message. Here is my configuration code:

```
    public static void UseMassTransit(this IServiceCollection services, MassTransitConfiguration massTransitConfiguration)
    {
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddConsumer<CustomerChangeConsumer>();
            x.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host(massTransitConfiguration.Host, h =>
                {
                    h.AccessKey(massTransitConfiguration.AccessKey);
                    h.SecretKey(massTransitConfiguration.SecretKey);
                    h.EnableScopedTopics();
                });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("CustomerChangeConsumer",
                    configurator =>
                    {
                        configurator.ConfigureConsumer<CustomerChangeConsumer>(context);
                    });

                cfg.Message<CustomerUpdate>(x =>
                {
                    x.SetEntityName("customerupdate.fifo");
                });

                cfg.Publish<CustomerUpdate>(x =>
                {
                    x.TopicAttributes["FifoTopic"] = "true";
                });
            });
        });
        services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
    }
```

Here is my publish code:

```
public class Publisher : IPublisher
{
    private readonly IPublishEndpoint _publishEndpoint;

    public Publisher(IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint)
    {
        _publishEndpoint = publishEndpoint;
    }

    public async Task PublishAsync(CustomerUpdate customerUpdate)
    {
        await _publishEndpoint.Publish(customerUpdate);
    }
}
```

Here is my error message:

`Invalid parameter: The MessageGroupId parameter is required for FIFO topics`

Here is the exception type:

`Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.Model.InvalidParameterException`

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleExceptionStream(IRequestContext requestContext, IWebResponseData httpErrorResponse, HttpErrorResponseException exception, Stream responseStream)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.<HandleExceptionAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1.<HandleAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.<ProcessExceptionAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.<InvokeAsync>d__7`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport.Contexts.AmazonSqsClientContext.<MassTransit-AmazonSqsTransport-ClientContext-Publish>d__18.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport.Transport.TopicSendTransport.SendPipe`1.<Send>d__5.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport.Transport.TopicSendTransport.SendPipe`1.<Send>d__5.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.<GreenPipes-IPipeContextSource<TContext>-Send>d__7.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.<GreenPipes-IPipeContextSource<TContext>-Send>d__7.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.<GreenPipes-IPipeContextSource<TContext>-Send>d__7.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

Apparently, I need to set the `MessageGroupId` somewhere. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `MessageGroupId` when publishing:

```
public class Publisher : IPublisher
{
    private readonly IPublishEndpoint _publishEndpoint;

    public Publisher(IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint)
    {
        _publishEndpoint = publishEndpoint;
    }

    public async Task PublishAsync(CustomerUpdate customerUpdate)
    {
        await _publishEndpoint.Publish(customerUpdate, x =>
            x.SetGroupId("SomeGroupId"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait for this to become available to make it work. https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/commit/90c619564817c8d6f2a0da6edc3851b2ce434672